# is the math induction proof wrong?

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Prove that for each positive integer n,

$$O_n+2=O_{n+1}$$Here $$O_n$$ is odd positive integer. That is$$O_1=1$$ $$O_2=3$$ etc.

My attempt:
Base Case: $$O_1+2=3$$ = $$O_2$$
$$
Inductive step: Suppose $$P(k) =$$O_{k}+2=O_{k+1}$$ is true

Adding 2 to both sides we get,

$$(O_k +2)+2=O_{k+1}+2$$

this implies $$O_{k+1}+2=O_{k+2}$$
I am doubtful about the last step. I think it is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How should I proceed for last step. Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of $O_n$? How do you know that $O_{k+1}+2 = O_{k+2}$?

Comment: $$O_n$$ is odd positive integer

Comment: That definition is satisfied if $O_n = 17$ for every $n$. I think you meant to say "the $n$th positive integer." But then I would ask for the definition of the $n$th positive integer. I can tell when an integer is odd, but how do I know it is the $13$th and not the $14$th?

Comment: My comments are not just about the proof; they concern the question itself. The question is ill-defined. It doesn't give you the tools to make a non-circular proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your last step is correct, and you showed that $P(k+1)$ is true and by induction $P(n)$ is true for all $n \ge 1$ which means that $O_n +2 = O_{n+1}$ is true for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Hi! According to Ryan the last step is incorrect as it is circular reasoning. How should I proceed then? I have seen some proofs where they use the circular reasoning to complete the induction.Thanks!

Comment: @NatashaJ: Your proof is good. Nothing wrong about it. But you should add a small detail at the beginning like $O_1 + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3 = O_2$ when you validated the base case.

Comment: OK! I will keep that in mind! Thanks again!

Comment: @NatashaJ: Sure will.